# How to build JDK 8 from sources repository

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Can anybody take me a good tutorial how to build/compile OpenJDK8u(Linux) from the sources.
All I known is this link http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u
But I don't understand which directory I should I use and etc...
Thanks.

Comment: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html

Comment: I had [answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947742/following-changes-in-jdk8-repository/12975452#12975452) time ago. Not sure if my answer is still valid, but you can give it a try. It used to work for me since I built JDK 8 from source all the time back then when they were first implementing the new lambda feastures..

Comment: _Why_ are you wanting to do this? I have been programming in Java since Java 1.1 and have never needed to compile the JDK.

Comment: Because It interesting for me. I have a plan  create my small profiler(AsyncGetCallTrace) and load it to JVM as agent :)

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo, very helpful  article, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [README](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8d39522b0f75/README) in the Repository. It has pretty short build Instructions. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Which Linux distributive I should use? More often I use Red Hat Ent Linux.It's good idea ?

Comment: I suggest Debian, because its is one of the best supported ones.